# Flexbox not honouring container height when percentage

Tags: css, flexbox

Simple scenario - I would have thought.

The idea is that app-bar is a fixed height - set at 56px. The content DIV beneath should fill the remaining space - the height of the container is around 320px, which is set using a percentage of the parent.

If I use `height:100%`, the flexbox doesn't kick in, however, if I use `height:320px` it does.

Any ideas? The height needs to be a percentage, as it's filling the responsive parent.

```
<header class="img-app-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="app-bar"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</header>

.img-app-bar {

    .container {

        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;

        background-color:Red;
        height:100%;

        .app-bar {
            flex:0;
        }
        .content {
            flex:1;

            background-color:Yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create a demo of the issue using snippet here or http://jsfiddle.net Post the vanilla CSS.

Comment: if you use height:100%, it won't work as `img-app-bar` doesn't have a height set - so it doesn't know what height to be 100% of

Comment: @Pete - it does, and it doesn't. The problem is that it is set using an aspect ratio technique. I use padding on a pseudo element to give it height, so if it had no contents whatsoever, it would still have a height, but I dont specifically set a height value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.img-app-bar` needs a height, too. Otherwise your `.container` takes 100% height of 0.

```css
body, html {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}

.img-app-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;

  background-color:Red;
  height:100%;
}

.app-bar {
  height: 56px;
}
.content {
  flex:1;

  background-color:Yellow;
}
```

```html
<header class="img-app-bar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="app-bar"></div>
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent element doesn't have a height css style, percentage height for the child it isn't going to work (unless you use the absolute positioning hack) - that's just the way css works

A work around for your situation is to do the following (the aforementioned absolute position hack):

```css
.img-app-bar {
  position: relative;
  /* the following is just for giving height without using height */
  padding-top: 300px;
  background: red;
}
.container {
  /*this seems to set a height without setting a height*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.app-bar {
  height: 56px;
  background: green;
}
.content {
  flex:1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="img-app-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="app-bar"></div>
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```